# Access website without Domain (Plesk Panel)

Tags: cpanel, plesk

In Cpanel i can access a website without domain using **http://IP/~username**. Is there any similar way to access a website without domain which is hosted in Windows & Running with Plesk panel.?

Answer (score 4):

most hosting provider set temporary url based on the server ip address and customized domain name

https://www.motherhost.com/help/temporary-url-for-the-domain-in-plesk-control-panel/

Any domain or server name followed by /~cpanelusername/ can be used to see that user's site. This will cause any domain on the server to show the site for the username. That's how cPanel setup works; so we can't prevent this method from showing someone else's site on your domain.
Hosting with Plesk 11
http://domainname.com.ipaddress.windowshostingdns.com/

(Be sure to replace all of the above with the actual values and to have the dashes between the IP octets instead of dots.)

The IP address can be either the IP for the A record or the control panel, based on which one is actively pointing to the site as A records can direct a domain name to point to a different server.

The best way to find the temporary URL from your Plesk control panel is to do the following:

```
Click on the Web Sites and Domains tab.
Click on the Domain Name for the hosting settings.
In the hosting settings, look for the preview link. This will provide the proper temporary URL.
```

Hosting with Plesk 10

(Be sure to replace "serverIP", "cpanelusername" and "path_aka_document_root" with the actual values.)
Hosting with Plesk 11

(Be sure to replace all of the above with the actual values and to have the dashes between the IP octets instead of dots.)
Hosting with Plesk 10

(Be sure to replace "serverIP" and "otherdomain.com" with the actual values.)
Hosting with Plesk 8 and 9

(Replace "ipaddress" with your server's IP address.)

Answer (score 1):

You may configure fake domain name , reconfigure HOST file in your PC and access to the site .

In HOST file put the fake domain + IP of the server , do an F5 and with that fake domain you may be able to access to it .

Answer (score 0):

in Plesk you unable to access website without domain.
But you can access live websites content via IP But need upload websites content in domain.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

You can access your plesk panel without domain.

You need to known you ip address.

You can access pleak panel using ip with port.

Http://ip:8443

Regards,

Stanley